# Selenium testing category

Tags: selenium, terminology

My question is more theoretical rather than code related. I am implementing a test through Selenium and my approach is to test the visual parts of my application(for ex. if all pages are visible, or if a specific element is placed in a page etc).

I am not sure in which category this test belong. In my mind it is not Unit Test because does not exam code behaviour. Neither Integration Test. I wonder if I can call this test Acceptance Test or User Acceptance Test.

Comment: Why not categorize it with something more meaningful?  Visual tests or something of the sort?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Categories are fixed: Unit Tests - Integration Tests - User Acceptance Tests (and after those are coming the manual tests). In other words I am asking if GUI tests are under the umbrella of UAT

Comment: Depends on what you're talking about?  While there are plenty of test categories and definitions out there, if you're trying to build a vocabulary to use at your company, there's nothing wrong with having a category called "Visual tests". 

There are plenty of types of tests beyond the ones you listed . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only testing the GUI of your application, then it is usually referred to as [GUI testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface_testing), which is often mistaken with GUI-based [system testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_testing).

Let's say you have a simple form with fields for first name, last name, address etc. In GUI testing, you would check if, for instance, the layout looks correctly throughout different browser or whether the validation of the form works as expected. GUI-based system testing aims to test the whole system via the GUI. For example, you would verify what the client sends to the server after the submit button is being pressed and how the latter responds.

The [Galen Framework](http://galenframework.com/) is an example for GUI testing, whereas [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) is typically used for GUI-based system testing.

Please bear in mind that the exact definition may vary from company to company.